# java collection slow conversion

Tags: java, collections

```
IMap<Long, Vehicle> mapVehicles = // get all vehicles , total 2500 unit
Collection<Vehicle> collectionVeh = mapVehicles.values(); // fast
// I want to sort it so wrap to ArrayList 
List<Vehicle> listVehicle = new ArrayList(collectionVeh .values()); // very slow
Collections.sort(listVehicle );// fast
```

How can i convert Collection to List very fastly ?

Thanks.

Comment: You comment that creating a new ArrayList from the output of Map.values() is very slow, but with a 2500 element map surely the difference is negligable?  In other words this looks like a micro-optimisation to me.

Comment: Kind of Map - for in memory data grid - hazelcast.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Collection` that's not a `List`, and you want to have it as a `List`, there is no faster way than to do something like `new ArrayList(yourCollection)`. (I don't believe that constructor does any unnecessary work that you could skip, so to speak.)

What you could do however is to change the original collection. If it's currently a `HashMap` your iteration will take time proportional to it's capacity. By changing to a `LinkedHashMap` you can iterate over it in time proportional to it's size. (Probably a negligible difference, but it could be worth a try.)

Comment: This is typo; it is already like that
List listVehicle = new ArrayList(collectionVeh); // very slow

Answer (score 2):

Is it faster if you drop the vehicles in a TreeSet instead?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try `Arrays.asList(collectionVeh.values().toArray)`? May be it will run faster?